# How to access executing instruction binary code (e.g., opcode) from C helper functions in QEMU

Tags: qemu, kvm

I would like to modify the QEMU emulator's behaviour when it executes some assembly instructions of a target architecture (e.g., RISC-V) running ontop of a host (e.g., x86).

My question is, is it possible, to access the information related to the instruction being executed, from the C helper?

There some infos that can be accessed from the context variable pointer, but I wasn't able to access the instruction binary code for example. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, is it possible, to access the information related to
>   the instruction being executed, from the C helper?

Yes. One way to do it is to pass this information to helper from a translator function. Another is to use `cpu_ld*_code` (e.g. `cpu_ldub_code`) in the helper to fetch instruction from memory.

Comment: Thanks! I managed to pass the Opcode as an argument to the Helper functions from the translator functions, by adding an additional argument to the instructions I'm interested in, then inside each corresponding translator function, I pass the Opcode (stored originally in a Context data structure) to the generated helper function.